# cygwin cp can't copy file "abc" because destination dir. contains file "abc.exe"

Tags: bash, cygwin, cp

I'm under Win10/x64 using cygwin64 bash.

I have a problem copying a simple directory (../bin below) which only contains 2 files, a Win10 executable and the corresponding executable for Linux (same file name with no extension).

```
$ ls  ../bin
abc  abc.exe*

$ cp -rf ../bin .
cp: cannot create regular file './bin/abc': File exists

$ ls bin
abc.exe*
```

Why the file abc is not copied !?

If I rename abc.exe to abcd.exe in ../bin, then it works and the 2 files are copied.

How to tell bash/cp to not consider abc and abc.exe as the same file ? I tried various cp options (-f, -p, -H) it does not solve the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. Besides this is not really a programming question.

Comment: This sounds like a peculiarity of Cygwin. They have to get around the fact that executables on Windows must have the `.exe` extension, but Unix executables usually don't have an extension. Therefore a file with a `.exe`  extension and another with the same name but no extension are treated as the same file by Cygwin. Probably not a good idea to have the two files in a `bin` directory in the first place as it will only confuse Cygwin. But if you really want to make the copy, easiest way is probably just to use Windows Explorer.

Comment: Note that the .exe must be a real Windows executable file to reproduce the issue. I created 2 dummy files in ../bin "xyz" and "xyz.exe" using "ls > xyz; chmod a+x xyz" then problem does not appear.

Comment: @Graeme. Yes it must be cygwin, but I thought there might be a way to change this behaviour ?  This is part of an automated build process, so manual copy is not possible. A workaround is obviously to rename the .exe file in ./bin to avoid the name conflict, but I don't have full control on this build process...

Comment: If they are the same file, try a symlink?

Comment: But why have the files without the extension under Cygwin anyway? They are not needed, Cygwin knows to run the `.exe` if you give it the name without `.exe`.

Comment: abc and abc.exe are different files. I need to copy them, not symlink, because the copies will be used in distribution packages.

Comment: Ok, but then you can't run `abc` under Cygwin, so why put it in a directory for executables?

Comment: Some context: actually the files to copy are launchers produced by the Netbeans IDE (that's why I have no full control on how files are generated). The abc.exe is the launcher for Windows, abc for Linux. Actually there is a 3rd one abc64.exe for Win64, but this one is copied OK because no name conflict. The cp -r is one of the numerous operations involved to prepare distribution packages for win, win32 and Linux.

Comment: Maybe do different folders? `bin`, `win32` and `win64` or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199800/discussion-between-jjazzboss-and-graeme).

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue on Cygwin with a real executable file.

Comment: I'm using cp (GNU coreutils) 8.26
Paquet réalisé par Cygwin (8.26-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is to do with the special way in which Cygwin handles `.exe` files. If you have a file in your current directory say, `test.exe`, Cygwin has always allowed it to be executed by running `./test` without the `.exe` extension.

It does this inside its implementation of certain system calls which take a file name by checking if a file with the same name, but with the `.exe` extension exists, then operating on that instead. From a post on the Cygwin [mailing list](https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin/2009-08/msg00293.html):

> Cygwin always handled the .exe suffix transparently in terms of stat(2)
>   calls, but Cygwin 1.7 also handles them transparently in terms of
>   open(2) and any other call.  Therefore, if a file foo.exe exists, and an
>   application calls stat("foo"), it will get told that, yes, "foo" exists.
>   That's a basic component of being able to call foo.exe from bash by just
>   typing foo.  POSIX systems just don't have the .exe suffix for
>   executables.

However, this creates an issue where if a file already exists with the `.exe` extension, problems will arise if you try to create a file of the same name in the same directory without an extension.

Seemingly (as per the [mailing list](https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin/2009-08/msg00293.html) post), this usually occurs when extracting a tar file. In the case of the OP, it occurred when using the `cp -r` command to copy from a different directory where the files were created by a Windows IDE.

The workaround is to always create the file without the extension first, the create the `.exe` file. For this, instead of using `cp -r` it is possible to use the `pax` utility to copy non `.exe` files first. From *within the source directory*, do:

```
find . \! -name '*.exe' -print0 | pax -0drw dest_dir
find . -name '*.exe' -print0 | pax -0drw dest_dir
```

Note that the Cygwin `find` command does not support using `+` with `-exec` (which otherwise would be used for the preferred way to do this). Alternatively GNU `cpio` can be used:

```
find . \! -name '*.exe' -print0 | cpio -p --null dest_dir
find . -name '*.exe' -print0 | cpio -p --null dest_dir
```

Comment: I had to stop using cygwin git because of this problem. It gets very cranky when you have `file` and `file.exe` in the same repo folder.